# React Native - Access specific Key-Value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, api

I'm trying to console.log a specific value of a specific key in this case I want to only console.log the number 54.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8085/lastRoutineID/')
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      // .then(function (jsonData) {
      //   return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      // })
      .then(function (jsonStr) {
        that.setState({data: jsonStr});
        console.log('mount', jsonStr[0]);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('json data ' + this.state.data);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 24}}>
        <Text>hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


[
   {
     lastIdRutina: 54
   }
]
```

This is what I get in the terminal, I just want to console.log the number

```
[Thu Apr 08 2021 11:54:27.566]  LOG      json data [object Object]
[Thu Apr 08 2021 11:54:27.574]  LOG      mount {"lastIdRutina": 54}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value, you can use the `.` operator or subscript `[]`:

```
console.log('mount', jsonStr[0].lastIdRutina)
// or
console.log('mount', jsonStr[0]['lastIdRutina'])
```